# Which object to use for sorted in memory lookup data with gaps

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, .net-5

Which object can I use in C# net 5.0 to store the following information in memory to get the fastest retrieval of data?

Input : a number (long)

Example simplified lookup data:

```
1 -> 10          : ResultA
300 -> 300       : ResultB
500 -> 10000     : ResultC
235015 -> 235820 : ResultD
...
```

The list goes on (about 3 million rows of lookup data)

In the example data above:

```
Input -> output

5 -> ResultA
300 -> ResultB
400 -> Not found/null
9999 -> ResultC
1000000 -> Not found/null
```

Comment: I'm not sure if there's anything built-in (hopefully someone else can say if there is), but if there aren't overlaps in the ranges, you could build a sorted list and perform a binary search.

Comment: I'm not sure if/how a sorted list works if the exact unique key match isn't available. (ex: when searching for "9", the result should be the value of "1 -> 10"

Answer (score 1):

As Llama mentions the correct approach would be to use a binary search. This should provide sufficient performance even for many millions of ranges since it scales with O(log n) for reasonably well distributed data.

If ranges do not overlap something like this should work:

```
    // Assume sorted
        var rangesArray = new[]
        {
            (1, 10, "A"),
            (300, 300, "B"),
            (500, 10000, "C"),
            (235015, 235820, "D")
        };
        var rangesList = rangesArray.ToList();
        var toSearchFor = 9999;

        var comparer = new KeyComparer<(int, int, string), int>(p => p.Item1);
        var index = rangesList.BinarySearch((toSearchFor, 0, ""), comparer);
        if (index < 0) // negative values mean a exact match could not be found, 
        {
            // Take bitwise complement to get index of the element larger than the toSearchFor
            // remove one get the actual range to check
            index = ~index -1; 
            if (index > 0 && toSearchFor < rangesList[index].Item2 )
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Found Range {index}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Not Found");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Found Exact Range {index}");
        }
```

How to write a generic IComparer

```
public class KeyComparer<T, TKey> : IComparer<T> where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
{
    private readonly Func<T, TKey> selector;
    public KeyComparer(Func<T, TKey> selector) => this.selector = selector;
    public int Compare(T x, T y) => selector(x).CompareTo(selector(y));
}
```

If you have overlapping ranges you might need to search all smaller indices, or use some more advanced search structure.

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach? Be aware that it takes only the start value into consideration, because you said you only have gaps but no overlapping. In that case it would get more complicated.

```
public static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var random = new Random();
        // Create a list with random items.
        var source = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000)
            .Select(_ => new SortableObject { Start = random.Next(100000) })
            .ToList();

        // Sort the list by using a dedicated comparer
        source.Sort(SortableObjectComparer.Default);
        // Define an element to search for
        var searchElement = new SortableObject { Start = 17432 };
        // Get the index of the best matching item
        var found = source.BinarySearch(searchElement, SortableObjectComparer.Default);

        if(found < 0)
        {
            // No exact match, get the best candidates.
            var nextElement = source[~found];
            var beforeElement = source[~found - 1];

            Console.WriteLine($"Element with lower start value: {beforeElement.Value}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Element to search {searchElement.Value}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Element with higher start value: {nextElement.Value}");
        }
        else
        {
            // Exact match
            var matchingElement = source[found];
            Console.WriteLine($"Element matching: {matchingElement.Value}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Element to search {searchElement.Value}");
        }
    }
}

public class SortableObjectComparer : IComparer<SortableObject>
{
    public static readonly IComparer<SortableObject> Default = new SortableObjectComparer();
    public int Compare(SortableObject x, SortableObject y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return 0;

        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null))
            return -1;

        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return 1;

        return x.Start.CompareTo(y.Start);
    }
}

public class SortableObject
{
    public long Start { get; set; }
    public long End { get; set; }
    public string Value => $"Result {Start}";
}
```